# Extracting numbers from an email address prior to the @ sign

Tags: regex, email, grep

I am hoping someone can help me (complete newbie to regex)

I am trying to extract only the email addresses with numeric entries before the @

for example

James@hotmail.com would not be selected

J4m35@hotmail.com would be selected

The other problem i have is that each email address also has a phone number afterwards in a ten digit format.

Example

James@hotmail.com 5555511111

J4m35@hotmail.com 5555511112

Everything i have tried seems to either select the phone number too or nothing at all.

Thanks in advance and apologies if there is not enough information. I will try and answer any questions people have.

Things i have tried so far

grep -E [0-9][@] data.csv

grep -E [0-9] data.csv

grep -E \d+(?=@) data.csv (this does not complete due to a syntax error)

As i say, i'm a complete novice at this and still trying to get my head round the regex stuff

Comment: Can you add the code you tried? So we can fix it (click "edit" below your question).

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez edited question to reflect my feeble attempts :)

Comment: Doesn't `grep -E [0-9][@]` work for you? It fetches `J4m35@hotmail.com 5555511112`

Comment: Apologies, there are around 1000 email addresses in the file and i need to get any which have a number at any point before the @, i need it to only give me the email address and no include the phone number digits as i need to know how many match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```sh
grep -Eo '^[^@[:space:]0-9]*[0-9][^@[:space:]]*@[^[:space:]]+' file
```

**Details**

- `^` -  start of string
- `[^@[:space:]0-9]*` - zero or more chars other than a `@`, whitespace and a digit
- `[0-9]` - a digit
- `[^@[:space:]]*` - zero or more chars other than a `@`, whitespace and a digit
- `@` - a `@` char
- `[^[:space:]]+` - one or more chars other than whitespace.

See an [online demo](https://ideone.com/KxIFLi):

```sh
s='James@hotmail.com 5555511111
J4m35@hotmail.com 5555511112
J4ll@hotmail.com 6453453344'
grep -Eo '^[^@[:space:]0-9]*[0-9][^@[:space:]]*@[^[:space:]]+' <<< "$s"
# => J4m35@hotmail.com
#    J4ll@hotmail.com
```

Comment: This works to a point, the email addresses may have any characters before the @ and i need to extract all which have a 0-9 in any position before the @. 

Can i simply add more [^@[:space:]0-9] to increase the number of points it searches?

Comment: @WhiteDuck If you mean there can be spaces, too, just remove `[:space:]` before `@`. Then use `grep -Eo '^[^@0-9]*[0-9][^@]*@[^[:space:]]+'`

Comment: Amazing thank you! That worked at treat. I was then able to -c to get the number of matches

Answer (score -1):

Try something like:
\w*\d+\w*[@]\S*

explanation:

- arbitrary number of word characters
- then at least one digit
- more arbitrary number of word characters
- the @
- everything behind it until the next space

Comment: edit: from your question it's not clear if there should be a digit directly in front of the @ or anywhere in front of the @. In case it should be directly in front of the @ it has to be: \w*\d+[@]

Comment: It is not a valid POSIX ERE expression that OP uses

Comment: Using the grep -E \w*\d+\w*[@]\S* i'm getting the any 'd' before the @ as a result. I need to find the digit anywhere prior to the @ in the address without pulling out the phone numbers too

Comment: you mean it gives you the whole line including the phone numbers? You can tell grep to only give you the matched patterns as output using the -o switch (or --only-matching). So, in conclusion try >>grep -o "\w*\d+\w*[@]\S*" [file...]

Comment: @PeterDeckenbacher no, for some reason it was brining up all the email addresses with a d in them instead of the digit it should have. Solved now so thank you guys so much for your input, it is much appreciated